# Remove id form embeded documents

Tags: mongodb

Hi i have embedded document like this:
I want to remove  "id_group" of worker because its unnecessary and change format date to correct. I need agregate function to to this? What is easy way to do this?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6242d36461e63768f0ac1529"
    },
    "id_z": 10,
    "name": "Journalists",
    "addres": "New York",
    "workers": {
        "worker": [{
            "id_worker": 15,
            "name": "example",
            "job": "example",
            "id_director": 25,
            "hired": "2005-02-20",
            "id_group": 10
        }, {
            "id_worker": 16,
            "name": "example",
            "job": "example",
            "id_director": 26,
            "hired": "2005-02-20",
            "id_group": 10
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the field from the DB you can use [$unset](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "workers.worker.$[].id_group": ""
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

And this query will remove all `id_group` from all objects.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lbcTVo0K_MU)

Also, what if you want is to not output the value simply use [projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection) and the value will not be shown but will be still in DB.

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "workers.worker.id_group": 0
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d4HCjty8sZ1)

And for aggregations queries you can use [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in the same way... [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tavh8Qwaw1D)